# Mobx : Transaction

Tags: reactjs, transactions, mobx

Q1:Do we need transaction , when an observablearray.replace is used ?

as per this link 
https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/transaction.html

it mentioned during push of each item.

Q2:Does Transaction improve the performance  or its just to wrap so that render happens only after the transaction is completed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observers are not notified until after the replace is complete, so there is no need for a transaction, as [demonstrated by this example](http://jsbin.com/majesufalo/edit?js,console,output).

Transaction is just a way to avoid observers from being synchronously notified of a change in observables until the transaction is done.